# Template Error on Form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

I have an nested model student that belongs to a high_school.  The problem is that when I go to create a new student (/high_schools/1/students/new) I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"students", :high_school_id=> # <HighSchool id: 1, name: "cool place", ... }

<%= form_for @student, :url => high_school_student_path(@high_school, @student), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

I think I'm just doing something really simple and stupid that I can't think of.

My environment: Rails3 and Ruby1.9.2dev

Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. A generic, RESTful model is throwing a 'no route matches' on the destroy action of that resource.

Eric: would you happen to be using the Responders gem?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing an array as the first arg to form_for, and remove the :url hash.

```
<%= form_for [@high_school, @student], :html => { :multipart => true } %>
```

And be sure that @student is a new record.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add

```
delete 'student' => :destroy
```

in routes.rb

controller :students do

```
     delete 'student' => :destroy
```

end